# wait for page load with protractor in Bootstrap App

Tags: typescript, protractor, bootstrapping

Is the way to wait for page load with the protractor in Bootstrap App?
I can not find good information about it.

Comment: Can you clarify your question?

Answer (score 0):

first you should see if page is loaded which elements are appeared in page or what changes when page loaded, and expect that happen . there are many ways to check based on your application you can check if page url is changed and what is your expectation or by `browser.waitForAngular();`
wait for angular to load or for checking if `DOM` loaded or not execute a simple script and expect result in your protractor test something like:
`<body onload="script();">` and etc.

Answer (score 0):

There are two potions the ugly one and the good one .

1. `browser.sleep(time)` which I highly discourage because your tests
   will fail if there is a network issues or your loading page time changes .
2. the seconds option is to make `brower.wait()` you can learn more about it in the protractor [doc](http://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=webdriver.WebDriver.prototype.wait) which will give a promise and wait for it to be resolved .